# Regex to match each n digit has at least one digit 1

Tags: javascript, regex

I am new in regex and JavaScript. I need to solve a problem with JavaScript. I have given a string of binary of any length. I need to find each n digit of binary contains at least one "1". If each n digit have at least one "1" then OK. But if not i need to return the minimum number of "1" replace with "0" to achieve the required result.
suppose the binary =00100 and n=2.(I need to calculate each two digit contains at least one "1" digit).
then i need to transform the string like this 01101. and return 2 because i replace two "0" with "1";
I think it can be done with regex easily. But i don't know how to do this. Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: suggest detail explain with colums, samples and anertashuns

Comment: regex is a poor match for this problem.  just iterate over the digits normally

Comment: if you really want to use regex, you can use a replacer function to increment a counter, or collect matches, which would be pretty much the same as iterating it normally

Comment: For readers unfamiliar with the word "anertashuns", it's early-English for "gusto".

Answer (score 0):

I've made a wild guess at what you are trying to do. I assume you are given a string of zeroes and ones and wish to substitute `'1'` for each `'0'` that is followed by fewer than `n` characters or if there is at least one `'1'` among the following `n` characters.

Here are two strings.

```
0011000010010100000
1111011111111100111
```

The first is converted to the second if, when `n = 3`, each match of the first string by the following regular expression is converted to `'1'`:

```
/0(?=.{0,2}(?:$|1))/
```

Here `2` equals `n-1`.

[Start your engine!](https://regex101.com/r/FWE5Ev/3/)

Javascript's regex engine performs the following operations.

```
0           : match '0'
(?=         : begin a positive lookahead
  .{0,2}    : match 0-2 characters
  (?:$|1)   : match the end of the string or '1'
)           : end positive lookahead
```